# Tor browser 6.5-A1 not showing circuit

Tags: circuit, update

i just updated Tor to the newest version (6.5-A1) and i have a problem.
since the update, for every site, when i try to look at the circuit, i just see this: [image: Menu shows 'tor circuit for this site: (example.com) Example A, Example B, Example C']

While it should be like this

[image: Menu shows IP's and countries of origin.]

While its not a major problem, more comfort than anything, i really dont like this and feel a little unsafe. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Salami.

Comment: unable to reproduce this on 6.5a1 linux64. will test windows later.

Comment: tested on windows 10, still unable to reproduce.

Comment: There is a bug report about it: https://bugs.torproject.org/19335